# How to extract span value from html using xpath in c#?

Tags: c#, html, xpath

1. I am stuck in a problem i just want to extract data from x-path attribute 
   selector this is the div and span who's inner text want to show please help me 
   out.
2. I am also performing this option in 16 times in a for each loop.

   ```
   <div class="l">
   <span id="ls_title_7596012" class="ls_h_desc" title="Required 10 marla 
   old house in any block of bahria town">Required 10 marla old house in 
   any block of bahria town</span>
   </div>
   ```
3. I am also trying this but not succeed.

   ```
    var name=htmlDocument?.DocumentNode?.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"1\"]//span[@class=\"ls_h_desc\"]//title")[0].InnerText;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if you need to get "title" attribute value:

```
var title = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id = 'ls_title_7596012]'").getAttribute("title").value
```

or

```
var title = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id = 'ls_title_7596012]/@title'")
```

and if you need to get inner text you could try :

```
var text = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id = 'ls_title_7596012]'").InnerText
```

or

```
var text = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id = 'ls_title_7596012]/text()'").InnerText
```

Comment: this will give me a static value in 1 time in above question i say need these values in 16 time which is in this tag also thanks for you suggestion

Comment: If the "Id" attribute is different for these 16 times, you can use the "class" attribute, if it's the same each time

`var text = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class = 'ls_h_desc']").InnerText`
or

`var title = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class = 'ls_h_desc']").getAttribute("title").value`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to utilize HtmlAgilityPack with css selector. There is a package do this jobs https://github.com/hcesar/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelector

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {


    var html = @"<div class=""l"">
<span id=""ls_title_7596012"" class=""ls_h_desc"" title=""Required 10 marla 
old house in any block of bahria town"">Required 10 marla old house in 
any block of bahria town</span>
</div>";

        // Try HtmlAgilityPack with css selector
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        IList<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.QuerySelectorAll("div.l #ls_title_7596012");
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(nodes);
        Assert.AreEqual(nodes.First().InnerText, "Required 10 marla old house in \r\nany block of bahria town");


        // try with xpath
        var xpath = @"//*[@id=""ls_title_7596012""]";
        nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(nodes);
        Assert.AreEqual(nodes.First().InnerText, "Required 10 marla old house in \r\nany block of bahria town");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also use HtmlAgility Pack with x path but not succed